# How do I prevent 'file_get_contents' breaking the CSS styles on my parent page

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, file-get-contents

**SUMMARY:**

When I use 'file_get_contents' to display a 3rd party webpage inside my webpage I often find the CSS from the 3rd party webpage adversely affects the style of my webpage.

How can I protect my styles from the CSS of the 3rd party webpage?

**DETAIL:**

**What I want to happen:**

- user visits [www.mypage.com] which contains banner content I need to
  display, plus a    URL text box
- user enters "www.3rdparty.com" in the text box and presses 'submit'
- 3rd party page shows within [www.mypage.com] under the banner content (which needs to stay)

**My method:**

- the 'submit' button makes an ajax request - to file [myphpfile.php]
- the [myphpfile.php] file uses 'file_get_contents' to grab the [www.3rdparty.com] webpage
- ajax lands the [www.3rdparty.com] webpage inside [www.mypage.com]
- I can get all of this to work fine (functionally)

**The problem:**

Once the above is complete some [www.3rdparty.com] webpages change the CSS of my banner content (presumably as these are loaded AFTER the CSS of the [www.mypage.com] webpage).

How can I protect the styles in the [www.mypage.com] page so that the banner content is not affected?

I've tried various ways (e.g. enclosing the ajax 'landing area in [www.mypage.com] with a DIV having a specific NAME/ID - also tried naming my BODY with a unique name). None of these fix the issue.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

**EDIT** - I can't use an iframe as once the Ajax load is complete I use JQuery to allow the user to hover over the elements inside [www.3rdparty.com]

Comment: Use an `<iframe>`better?

Comment: Would it be possible to use the HTML DOM Parser and remove the css styles and the scripts ?

Comment: You could possibly use html5 scoped style to make sure your page style takes priority. However, it may mess with the page that you are loading in since the scoped css overrides all css base on that id/class before it. I think @moonwave99 is right when he says use an iframe.

Comment: EDIT - I can't use an iframe as once the Ajax load is complete I use JQuery to allow the user to hover over the elements inside [www.3rdparty.com]

Comment: that's only one problem you will have, there are numerous other ones such as relative paths to resources as well as security issues dumping unknown code into your page.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with the basics of your html page in it? And what jquery plugin are you using that won't work in an iframe? I'm sure there's a way around that restriction.